# Vuejs template not updating applying filter to property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple template that iterates over some items:

```
<template v-for="card in filteredCards">
```

filteredCards are a property I am using to filter some results by clicking a simple html link. In my Vue component I have this:

```
data = {
    cards: '',
    filteredCards: ''
}
```

cards is the original data coming via an ajax request - and filteredCards is what I'm actually iterating over.

The problem becomes when I do any kind of update with a filter - the template is not reflecting the filtered array. Here is how I'm filtering:

```
this.filteredCards = this.cards.filter(function (item) 
{
    return item.Data.event_type.match('something_test');
});
```

In devtools I can see that the array has been updated to only a single item - however the template never updates and leaves all the results showing. If I call something that actually mutates the array though like reverse - the template updates just fine. Is there something I need to do in order to force an update after filtering the array?

---

I've updated a bit to reflect using a custom filter. I'm still running into the same problem.  In devtools I see that the filterKey is being updated from an event broadcasted from the parent instance.  But nothing is being updated in the template.

```
var $data = {
    cards: [],
    filterKey: '',
    loading: true
};


Vue.component('cards', {
    template: '#card-template',

    data: function()
    {
        return $data;
    },

    events: {
        'updateFilterKey': function(key)
        {
            this.filterKey = key;
        }
    }
});

Vue.filter('onlyMatching', function(cards)
{
    var $this = this;

    return cards.filter(function(item)
    {
        return item.Data.event_type.match($this.$data.filterKey);
    });
});
```

The code that initially gets the data is just a simple ajax call:

```
var getFeed = function($url)
{
    $.get($url, function(response)
    {
        $data.loading = false;
        $data.cards = response;

    }).fail(function()
    {
        $data.loading = false;
    });
};
```

The strange thing is with this current code - when I click back and forth between sending different keys the actual array items are being duplicated in my template over and over when I click the "all items" which sets the filterKey to an empty string.

Comment: What you're trying should work - you should be able to set `this.filteredCards` to a new array and the template should reflect that. Could you post some more of your component code? It might help to see how the data is set after the ajax call and maybe also the full method where it gets filtered ...

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is absolutely backwards.

You actually want to loop the **original** array but apply a filter on it.

```
<template v-for="card in cards | filterBy onlyMatching">
```

Then, in your code, create a [custom filter](http://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-filter):

```
Vue.filter('onlyMatching', function (cards) {
    return infoBlocs.filter(function(item) {
        return item.Data.event_type.match('something_test');
    });
})
```

This should totally work. Now, whenever the array is changed in any way, the filter will get triggered and the list will be re-rendered.

Comment: I've tried using a custom filter like that - but the issue I keep running into is that the filter key needs to dynamically change based on what is clicked on the html link.  Something like 

    updateFeedFilterKey('something_test')

Where that filter key actually gets passed in as a condition to filter by.

Comment: There's no problem with that since you can use a filter like this `| onlyMatching someFilterElement` and `someFilterElement` is something you have defined as a variable. Then you can use it in the filter function (`Vue.filter('onlyMatching', function (cards,someFilterElement) {`) and filter accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out the filtering was working all along.  There's an issue with the conditional templating.  I'll ask that in another question.